# Can you disable the on-screen control guide?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I’ve been playing on the normal mode (not the assist mode) and I’m getting a little sick of the controls being shown on screen so much.

I thought it was just going to be for the first short world, but it’s still around in the desert. I understand the helpfulness for when you’re controlling a captured character, but I get them when I’m just running around and it’s telling me how to jump and do the basic throw.

Is there a way to disable this “feature”?

Comment: No, and given the sheer amount of things there is to possess in this game, it is actually surprisingly helpful.

Comment: Like I said, the capture abilties are useful, but telling me how to jump every 5 minutes is annoying.

Comment: I haven’t actually seen these appear past the first area. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I believe they only pop up when you read a sign.  The signs always seem to have the same model and texture so they are easy to spot and avoid.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann I think that may be worth posting as an answer

Comment: I think it may be worth adding in that this happens to you mostly in Two-player.  Based on comments throughout, this isn't a big issue in single player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I   have been googling this for a week. There is no fix. As a matter of fact this is the first topic I have came across regarding this issue, so I am wondering if not everyone is affected.  I do see the problem in a few reviewers that have the issue in their capture footage but never mention the annoyance that it is. The issue pops up when you are far from any hint sign or away from any enemies to capture, so it is unavoidable.

It is even worse in 2p mode as it keeps telling you howto move, jump and look around.  As if I got 200 moons in my play through without ever figuring that out.  It is annoying for me too and I hope a patch fixes this obvious glitch.

EDIT :  I fount a tiny topic on the Nintendo support forum. It looks like you can forward your input to Nintendo support directly. Which I am doing so right now. (If I can find where to submit a question about games&apps to Nintendo.)

https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/70749

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is happening?  I don't recall seeing any controls unless I'm reading a hint, climbing something,  or just possessed someone with cappy.

Comment: Anytime I am walking around , standing (near or away from anything, doesn't matter). There is a control tutorial that shows up just below the screen's center. As if it was your first time playing. This does not involve going near the hint signs.  When you have hours sunk into a game it should not continue to tell you the most basic controls that you haves performed countless times. I have logged this issue in screenshots and videos showing late game footage with 1st hour control prompts.  I don't mind going up to a NPC and having the A prrompt. I do not need to be told how-to swim or jump.

Comment: Have you tried 2p mode yet ? Try it out and you will see how much worse the prompt issue is. ~90% of my game play is in 2p so my issues are more in line of what you can experience with a friend .  The game should be set up to show you a control prompt a couple times each time you add or remove a player,  but not continuously through a un-broken 8 hour play through.  - Imo though.

Comment: @Tyler The bulk of my play time has been 2 player, and that's what has the most! It's every time we stop to look around with the camera it shows us how we can look around with the camera, or move and jump.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an option to disable any control tips on-screen while playing.  However, there are two types of tips, and one of them can be avoided outright.

For the first few seconds after you capture an enemy or if you stand still, the game will give you instructions because every enemy capture behaves a little differently.  This is unavoidable.

The other type of hint comes with a gameplay demo video in the bottom-right corner of your screen.  These only pop up **after you read a sign** detailing the displayed move.  These signs always look the same, and signs of that nature never have any non-control related information (at least in my experience), so I would simply avoid them if you don't want to see the instructions.

[image: Mario reading the instruction sign]

Comment: I kind of clarified in the comments, but it doesn't have anything to do with captures, and it happens regardless of reading signs. It just shows the basic controls to use the camera and to attack whenever I'm standing around, or sometimes as I'm running around. And then it sticks around for a while after I start moving.

Comment: That seems to be a result of playing 2-player mode then, because that doesn't occur during typical 1-player gameplay.